# Interactively matching beginning of region

Tags: regular-expressions, region

Short version: If i bound the scope of a search/replace to a region in the buffer (via the second/third optional argument of `search-forward` and its derivates), how can i match the beginning of that region?

---

Longer version: Say, i have a test.txt which contains only

```
xxx yyy xxx xxx yyy xxx xxx yyy xxx xxx yyy xxx xxx yyy xxx
xxx yyy xxx xxx yyy xxx xxx yyy xxx xxx yyy xxx xxx yyy xxx
xxx yyy xxx xxx yyy xxx xxx yyy xxx xxx yyy xxx xxx yyy xxx
```

Now, I mark any part and like to run `M-x query-replace-regexp` to replace the first three characters of the marked region. How can i achieve this with a regular expression? A naïve try would be to use

```
(defun test-1 (b e)
  (interactive "r")
  (query-replace-regexp "^..." "zzz" nil b e)
 )
```

but `^` matches only `bol` (and so does `` \` ``  ), not the beginning of my region. In extension, i need a similar construction in a larger script that could be simplified to the following minimal example:

```
(defun test-2 ()
  (interactive)
  (while (search-forward "xxx xxx" nil t)
    (let ((beg (match-beginning 0))
          (end (match-end 0)))
     (query-replace-regexp "^xxx" "zzz" nil beg end)
     (goto-char (match-end 0)))))
```

Is there a way to match the beginning of any substring within a regionally bounded regular search?

---

I am aware that you could avoid the problem by working with `narrow-to-region` and thus make the beginning of the region the sub-buffer's bol but i'd like to avoid this for the sake of context when I replace stuff in my documents.

Comment: While I don't understand your reasoning for avoiding narrowing (narrow, process, widen -- where's the issue?), perhaps you're looking for `\=` which "matches the empty string, but only at point."  Refer to `C-h i g (elisp)Regexp Backslash`

Comment: I need to see the surrounding context when deciding whether or not to replace a match in my RL case. This is difficult then only the broader match itself is visible. edit: `(query-replace-regexp "\=." "z" nil b e)` doesn't work, and `M-x query-replace-regexp <RET> \=. <RET> z<RET>` replaces every character in the region iteratively by `z`.

Comment: I'm really struggling to fathom what you're trying to achieve here.  `looking-at` would tell you whether there's a regexp match starting from point, and then you can conditionally run your query replace for that same regexp, only if there was a match -- *but* I don't believe you want to be using a `query-replace` command at all.  It sounds to me like you should query the user yourself, and use `replace-match` to do the replacement.  The query-replace commands are really intended to be called interactively.

Comment: @phils i know. the function test-1 is just for the purpose to illustrate what arguments are given to qrr. The same problem holds by marking a region and calling qrr interactively (which then only matches within said region). For short: I want to access the beginning of this region within the regexp. how do i do that, if possible at all?

Comment: Narrowing (or otherwise extracting and acting on the substring in question) is the only solution I know of.

Comment: What @phils said. Analyze whatever you need to in the surrounding context first, then `save-restriction` and `narrow-to-region`. Query the user and use `replace-match`. As for testing for a match at the beginning of the region: that's testing at point - `looking-at`. And no, there is no regexp special construct to match at region beginning/end.